# PHP shell_exec not working when adding options Ubuntu Apache2

Tags: php, ubuntu, apache2, openvpn

I'm trying to run a command from PHP to disconnect a user from OpenVPN Access Server

```php
    $output = shell_exec('sacli --user test --client_reason EXPIRED DisconnectUser');
    echo "<pre>$output</pre>";
```

This won't work and doesn't disconnect user, I confirmed the full command works in the terminal.

If I just use shell_exec('sacli'); or shell_exec('sacli --help'); it will echo successfully:

```php
sacli: No command specified

Use --help to show usage
```

Any help is appreciated,

Thanks!

Comment: `I confirmed the full command works in the terminal.` as the same user you are running php as via http?

Answer (score -1):

The most common problem here is that you're not running it with sudo or as root user. Do that and it should work fine

Comment: Are you suggesting `shell_exec('sudo sacli…`?

Comment: no, which user run this application this user have proper privilege or not i suggesting that thing.

Comment: That amounts to the same thing. It’s implied in the question this is http, not cli (because it has html in it) - running php with root privileges is a _huge_ risk and not something to recommend. It does indeed sound like a permission problem, fixing permissions so the php user can run that command if that’s the intention does sound like the necessary approach. -1 as written.

Comment: I have added www-data to sudoers for testing purposes, so permissions shouldn't be an issue:
www-data ALL=(ALL) NOPASSWD: ALL